# Density of universe lifting functor in type theory

Tags: ct.category-theory

For some context, this is part of a larger story on relative monads, I have asked about a generalization of the Topos of coalgebras construction to the relative case [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466754/when-is-the-eilenberg-moore-category-of-a-relative-monad-between-two-topoi-a-top).

The linked proposition 2.5 from [Relative monadicity](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.10405) in the comments to that question, treating the limits in relative Eilenberg-Moore category works without density assumptions. But some other statements in Relative monadicity do require density assumption.
As such I am curious about the density of the lifting functor between $Set_l$ and $Set_{l+1}$ in  type theory, which simply embeds smaller category of sets into the category of sets one universe above within type theory. If I understand correctly this functor would be dense in the bicategorical sense in $Cat$ if it's a 1-categorically dense functor. It is one of the motivating functors for relative monads. Is this functor dense?

Or alternatively within set-theoretic foundations, the similar statement but with Grothendieck universes and the categories of Sets defined with them.
For type-theoretic system I mean something like HoTT with resizing + universes and univalent categories with Set being the category of h-sets or alternatively MLTT.

Comment: The question about type theory seems ill-defined unless you fix the system involved/what categories you have in mind. If the question is restricted to considering Grothendieck universes, can't we note that every set is generated by colimits from the point, so any subcategory of sets containing the singleton will be dense?

Comment: @danielgratzer that might work I have been working with the fully faithful restricted yoneda embedding formulation in type theory mostly and that one seems to not line up correctly with universe size, so maybe the generated by colimits could work, i need to double check the details